# Apex 5/Universal Theme - Cant create a carousel region with slides

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm trying to create a carousel region in Oracle Apex 5 and am struggling. What I have tried so far is to create a "Static Content" region with a template of "Carousel Container" containing some sub regions in the "Slides" section of the layout. This does not work. When I run the page I don't see any carousel controls in my region, instead I just see what looks like standard nested regions. What am I missing?

[image: Apex 5 Carousel]

It feels like this should be a straightforward thing to achieve, but I've struggled to find much information on how to achieve it. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Weird - I just tried this. Simply defined a region with the template, made 2 sub regions in it. Works fine. You're doing this on apex.oracle.com I suppose? Is it a new application?

Comment: Yes, it's on apex.oracle.com. It isn't a new application. It's an old application that initially used one of the old themes. I might try starting a new application from scratch using the Universal theme. Worth pointing out that the other region types seem to be working fine.

Comment: I did create a completely new application. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it - but it might. By any chance, is there custom javascript on the page?

Comment: Yes, there is a bit of JavaScript. I've already checked the console and there are no errors.

Comment: I've sorted it now. I had some 3rd party JavaScript libraries included in the User Attributes for my theme, such as Bootstrap and Angular. Having removed these, the carousel now displays correctly, so there may be some compatibility issues involving these libraries. Thanks for your input.

Comment: No problem, good thing it's solved. Figured it had to be something like that :) Better post your 'solution' as the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved by removing a reference to the Bootstrap library from User Interface Attributes in Shared Components.

[image]

I am guessing there are some compatibility issues between Bootstrap and the Universal Theme JS/CSS. I was using Bootstrap version v3.0.3.