# Steps to create carousel container in Oracle APEX

Tags: carousel, oracle-apex

I try to create a carousel container in Oracle APEX, but the result is only show one value. When I click on the next or previous button, nothing happened.

May I know how to create a carousel container?

[image: carousel container only show one value]

Comment: How exactly have you created it? Describe all steps. Also, look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693889/apex-5-universal-theme-cant-create-a-carousel-region-with-slides

Comment: @Dmitry I am new in Oracle APEX and looking for the way to create a carousel container. I just drag the container into Content Body. I keep on looking for the tutorial to create carousel container but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create simpliest carousel container:

1. Create 3 regions with names, for example, `Region 1`, `Region 2`, and `Region 3`
2. Set value `Carousel Container` in `Template` property for `Region 1`
3. Set `Region 1` as parent region for regions `Region 2` and `Region 3` (region properties -> `User Integface` -> `Parent Region`)

Now you have region `Region 1` with two carousel elements - `Region 2` and `Region 3`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Dmitry. I will follow your steps to create the Carousel Container later.